# Black background when rotating image with PHP

Tags: php

I´m trying to rotate a PNG image with PHP. The image rotates but a black background appears.

This is my code:

```
$image = $_GET['image'];
$degrees = $_GET['degrees'];

header('Content-type: image/png');
$source = imagecreatefrompng($image) ;
$rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);
imagesavealpha($rotate, TRUE);
imagepng($rotate);

return rotate;
```

Comment: would it be an acceptable solution to use Javascript to do the rotate on the client-side instead of PHP on the server?

Comment: PHP's not going to magically do a Photoshop-style content-aware fill to fill in the triangles of background exposed by the rotation. It's up to you to provide something to fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

also add the line

```
imagealphablending($rotate, true);
```

before

```
imagesavealpha($rotate, TRUE);
```

Source: [Comment in PHP imagerotate](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.imagerotate.php#103029)

Comment: not working for me

Comment: also not working for me.